# Cannot connect Google App Maker to external mysql database

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-app-maker

I am trying to connect Google App Maker to MySQL database on digital ocean.
Life of me I can't get going, I  went through every possible forums and article.

Initially, I had a droplet with MySQL with SSL setup, then I configured another server with a simple setup, with no firewalls, no SSL. Still, I am getting this error.

> Error: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username, and password.

### Stak Trace from Google App Maker

Fri Aug 03 22:57:41 GMT+1000 2018
Error: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. at connectDB (dbConnection:85) at datasources.employee.script:1

Fri Aug 03 22:57:41 GMT+1000 2018
Executing query for datasource employee: (Error) : Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.
at connectDB (dbConnection:85)
at datasources.employee.script:1

Fri Aug 03 22:57:41 GMT+1000 2018
Executing query for datasource employee failed.

I have set up the MySQL to listen to `0.0.0.0` (any interface), then the MySQL user to connect remotely with any ip '%'

```
 host      | user           | plugin                |
 +---------+----------------+-----------------------+
 | %       | user           | mysql_native_password |
```

Here is my db connection string

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:3306/example','user', 'password');
```

1. i can remotely connect to the db using mysqlworkbench
2. i can connect using my local PHP setup using xampp.
3. I can connect from another remote ubantu box using mysql.

So I have isolated that there is no issue in connecting to db remotely.

Am I missing something that I need to setup in App App Maker?
I tried same connection on google appscript using google sheets, still didn't work.

I tried all possible methods of troubleshooting by isolating each possibility I am still unsuccessful for last two weeks.
If anyone can help or direct me where I am going wrong will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what connection details do you use when connecting from MySQL Workbench and PHP?

Comment: php connection code `
DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'appuser');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', '*****');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', '206.**.**.48');
DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'example');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
 die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().') '.mysqli_connect_error());
}
'   Also I tried the JDBC connection as well but i dont have the code now which i overwritten with above, For mySQL workbench used connection method: standard TCP/IP, hostname: 206.**.**.48, port: 3306, username:appuser, default schema: example

Comment: Can you post the full exception stack trace?

Comment: E
Fri Aug 03 22:57:41 GMT+1000 2018
Error: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. at connectDB (dbConnection:85) at datasources.employee.script:1
E
Fri Aug 03 22:57:41 GMT+1000 2018
Executing query for datasource employee: (Error) : Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.
at connectDB (dbConnection:85)
at datasources.employee.script:1
E
Fri Aug 03 22:57:41 GMT+1000 2018
Executing query for datasource employee failed.

Comment: Please **edit** your question with additional information, don't use comments, and it looks like this is not a MySQL error.

Comment: thanks mark, i have update the question